# Implementing in App Update Functionality In Android

Tags: android, app-update, in-app-update

I have followed the below mentioned step to integrate the in-app update.

1) Check for the update availability

```
  // Creates instance of the manager.
  val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context)

  // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
  val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo

 // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
 appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
 if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE

  // For a immediate update, use AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE
  && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)
) {
   // notify user that there is an available update
 }
}
```

2)If there is an update then trigger update flow

```
appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(

// Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
   appUpdateInfo,

// Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
   AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,

// The current activity making the update request.
   this,

// Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
   MY_REQUEST_CODE
)
```

In the first step when we are checking whether there is an update or not and whether the update is immediate or flexible.

Where are we specifying this update type which we will get in the first step?

I mean to say ki where do I have to specify whether my current update is immediate of force update?

Answer (score 1):

I have used this for force update or update later for app update and this worked with me.

And I am used app update using firebase

https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/force-app-update-androidfirebase/